# Branches order in branch/tag selector for pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have repo in Azure DevOps with `main` and `dev` branches.
Previously, `main` branch was the only one branch. Then we have added `dev`, and set it as default repository branch.
But still, when I run pipeline, drop-down list with branches shows `main` as the selected pipeline. When I click on list, `dev` branch is on the first place, but anyway `main` is selected by default, so I have to select `dev` manually all the time.

[image]

Is there a way to change order/set default branch for that **drop-down list**? So when developer runs pipeline manually, there will be default repository branch selected (which is `dev` in our case). I have made some investigation, but could not find the answer...

Note, that setting branches in `triggers` parameters in `yaml` file does not do the trick. It does not influence on branches order in that drop-down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the three dots in the YAML editor, & click on triggers:
   [image: Triggers setting from YAML editor]
2. Click on YAML tab & select the branch **dev** from the dropdown under *Default branch for manual and selected builds*
   [image: Branch selector]
3. Do remember to save the changes.
   [image: save changes]

---

As far as the order of branches is concerned, there isn't a way to change the order but you can **favorite** the branches by clicking on the star in front of branch name.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, but as I have highlighted in the question, triggers do not influence on that.

Comment: @kosist can you please try replicating the steps? because the settings to change default branch for a pipeline is hidden inside the triggers settings , and in fact, its not the trigger value there.

Comment: My fault. Thanks, indeed I didn't notice that YAML tab should be selected, and not Triggers.